# Why can't I convert to 8UC3 correctly?

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion

I want to perform my contouring in 8 bits even though my input image is in 16 bits. Given an input image of `raw` which is of type `16UC3`, I find the min / max value of each channel with

```
double min, max;
double min0, max0;
double min1, max1;
double min2, max2;

cv::minMaxLoc(raw, &min, &max);
cv::minMaxLoc(channel(raw,0), &min0, &max0);
cv::minMaxLoc(channel(raw,1), &min1, &max1);
cv::minMaxLoc(channel(raw,2), &min2, &max2);

fprintf(stderr, "max = %f %f %f %f!\n", max, max0, max1, max2);
```

where `channel` is defined by

```
cv::Mat channel(cv::Mat A, int ich) {
    cv::Mat C[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        C[i] = cv::Mat::zeros( cv::Size(A.rows, A.cols), A.type());
    }   
    cv::split(A, C); 
    return C[ich];
}
```

I then try to create a 8 bit image with

```
cv::Mat raw256(raw.clone());
raw.convertTo(raw256, CV_8UC3);
```

but when I print out the same information:

```
cv::minMaxLoc(raw256, &min, &max);
cv::minMaxLoc(channel(raw256,0), &min0, &max0);
cv::minMaxLoc(channel(raw256,1), &min1, &max1);
cv::minMaxLoc(channel(raw256,2), &min2, &max2);
```

I get very different results as shown:

```
max = 29952.000000 0.000000 29952.000000 26880.000000!
max = 255.000000 0.000000 255.000000 255.000000!
```

This causes a segfault later in my program as well. What am I doing wrong in my construction of `raw256` which is changing the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`convertTo` will saturate all values `>255` to `255`. That's why you're seeing those wierd values.

You can use `convertTo` with an appropriate scaling:

```
raw.convertTo(raw256, CV_8U, 1. / 256.);
```

This will in practice first your `raw` values to the range `[0, 255]`, and then safely convert them to `CV_8U`.

Notice that you can also use `normalize`:

```
normalize(raw, raw256, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
```

This will bring the lowest value in `raw` to 0, the highest to `255`, and the others scaled accordingly.

---

A side note, you don't need to pre-allocate `OutputArray`s, so you can write `channel` like this:

```
cv::Mat channel(cv::Mat A, int ich) {
    cv::Mat C[3];
    cv::split(A, C); 
    return C[ich];
}
```